# Soft brick Galaxy Tab s 10.5

Tags: unbricking, samsung-galaxy-tab

I have recently rooted and installed Blisspop rom to my Tab S.  I decided to revert back to the stock rom.  I download the rom for the UK and applied via Odin.  Download completed and the tab rebooted.  The tab is now stuck with the Samsung logo.  I can reboot in Odin recovery.  I have tried to download openrecovery-twrp tar expecting to see and use TWRP when going into recovery but I don't.  Help!

Comment: Do you have the exact model that you applied the ROM for? Is yours a UK version? Did you clear cache/wipe data? You will probably need to do that.

Comment: I suggest getting a recent copy of TWRP that is flashable with Odin This link will definitely be helpful: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-s/help/to-event-soft-brick-disaster-t2838473/post54618555#post54618555

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Follow the below steps to resolve it.

You must first find and then download the correct official stock firmware for your tablet via KIES:

1. Updating to the latest version of KIES program on your PC
2. Run KIES
3. Connect your Tab with Download mode to the PC with KIES.
4. KIES Menu Tools -> Firmware Upgrade and Initialisation -> Model name (your Model name Tab. For example SM-T800 or SM-T805) -> OK -> S / N (Serial Number of your Tab from sticker on original box Samsung or sticker on back cover of the Tab) -> OK -> OK -> OK
5. Turn on your Tab in the Download Mode ( press at the same time and hold for approximately 4 seconds the buttons Home, Power and Volume - and then press button Volume +)
6. Next step by step according to the instructions KIES